# How to Migrate Laravel solution from MS SQL Server to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, laravel, database-migration

I am newbie to Laravel 5 and 6. I have very specific question, solution was developed using laravel and MSSQL server as DB server. Now I want to change Database from MSSQL to MySQL, is there any automated way to achieve this ? Or how cumbersome is this process and what will be the step to achieve this?

Thanks & regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If with solution, you mean to migrate the logic and don't care about data.

- Simply create a new database in MySQL.
- Config `.env` file to use said db, for example:

  ```
  DB_CONNECTION=mysql
  DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
  DB_PORT=3306
  DB_DATABASE=my-db-name-here
  DB_USERNAME=root
  DB_PASSWORD=
  ```
- Clear all cache, like:

  ```
  php artisan config:clear --no-ansi
  php artisan cache:clear --no-ansi
  composer dump-autoload
  php artisan view:clear --no-ansi
  php artisan route:clear --no-ansi
  ```
- Test if the routes work, like:

  ```
  php artisan route:list --no-ansi
  ```
- At last, recreate DB structure, like:

  ```
  php artisan migrate --no-ansi
  ```

> If your project is new, there are no seed, else another useful command would be:
>
> ```
> php artisan db:seed --no-ansi
> ```

### But if Data are required:

The steps are basically the same as above;

But either you need to follow instructions at:
https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/03/mssql-to-mysql/

> Which shows how to directly copy data from source DB to destination.

Or you will need to:

- Export your MS SQL Server as SQL-file (or zip).
- Find/pick a tool, which converts SQL-files from  "MS SQL Server" syntax/format to "MySQL" format.
- Import resulting SQL-file in MySQL.

Comment: Thank you Top Master for reply. I do care about data. I try this without data as well.

Comment: @user940959 See update! - normally my Laravel Apps do not depend on data (and migrate is enough), but I understand that it's required in some cases ;-)